# localhost problem on my mamp server

Tags: mac, localhost, mamp

I'm new to mac, just own an iMac for a few days now. I installed mamp and everything was working fine, this morning I start it up and when I go to my phpmyadmin it's displaying an error:

> The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

but when I change the url from http://localhost to http://127.0.0.1 it works, any idea on how to fix this so it works with http://localhost.

also for some reason I can't browse the internet when my mamp server is running, I have to quit the program to surf the internet....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably switched how the MySQL server is running, binding to localhost or 127.0.0.1. Check the settings in MAMP.

Comment: I had mamp pro installed as well, might had a conflict. I did remove it but it's only after restarting that it seem to work correctly now.